# Is it possible to use only the syntax part of a syntax + indent Vim package?

Tags: vim, plugins

There is a Vim package that I'd like to use that does both indentation and syntax highlighting for a language. The highlighting is excellent but the indentation is terrible.

Is it possible for me to Vundle-install this package but only use the syntax highlighting part, disabling the indentation part? The package itself gives no way for me to do this and I'd prefer to not have to clone the package and modify its internals. I'd rather have some code in my .vimrc that will disable the unwanted parts.

Comment: Might be best to ask the package developer (or at least provide the plugin name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All (well-written) indent plugins start with this line:

```
if exists('b:did_indent') | finish | endif
```

So, you can disable the indent plugin by defining that variable before that script is sourced. One way to do this is putting a script `indent/{language}.vim` with

```
let b:did_indent = 1
```

into a directory that comes *before* the plugin in your `'runtimepath'`. Another is

```
:autocmd FileType {language} let b:did_indent = 1
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.